# com.android.library not find

Tags: android

I use gradle build my android code ,here is my build.gradle

```
 buildscript {

  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1'    
  }
}
```

so I can  apply 
`plugin:com.android.model.application` ,but when I want to depend a module , I got a error:

> error:plugin with com.android.library not find

which is my 
android library module's build.gradle begin with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library
```

if I write build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'


    }
}
```

I cannnot find
`plugin: 'com.android.model.application'` my question is what should I do to depend my library successfully

Comment: Actually what is your issue can you explain?You are facing error in library or application.

Comment: replace **apply plugin: 'com.android.library** with **apply plugin: 'android-library'** in your library gradle.

Comment: Why can't you add both classpath to dependencies closure?

Comment: @NigamPatro I am facing error with library,what should I do to resolve plugin with id 'com.android.library'not found ,I replace it with apply-plugin:'android-library',it's not work

Comment: @bigdestroyer sorry ,I don't know what do you mean ?if I add bot classpath ,it's unable to load class ' com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension'

Comment: @john_luo can you post the whole **gradle** file of your library.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to update the plugin to match the plugins available in the experimental build:

IE. change "com.android.library" to "com.android.***model***.library"

[**You can read more about it here on the experimental gradle build documentation.**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)
Search for "com.android.model.library" and you'll go right to it.

Be sure to read the other stuff in the doc; there are other differences you will have to add to your old library-model build.gradle file also. (eg. "targetSdkVersion 23" changes to "targetSdkVersion.***apiLevel*** 23"